# Chained lodash v3 functions returning object contents rather than key

Tags: javascript, lodash, ecmascript-5

I have a var `absurdPersonalities` which returns `Object {aipAggressive: Object, aipAir: Object, aipBot: Object, aipCautious: Object, aipDefender: Object…}` These objects each contain something that looks like:

```
adv_eco_mod: 1.3
adv_eco_mod_alone: 0.85
basic_to_advanced_factory_ratio: 0
display_name: "!LOC:Absurd"
enable_commander_danger_responses: true
energy_demand_check: 0.8
energy_drain_check: 0.65
fabber_alone_on_planet_mod: 2
fabber_to_factory_ratio_advanced: 1
fabber_to_factory_ratio_basic: 1
factory_alone_on_planet_mod: 0.5
factory_build_delay_min: 0
go_for_the_kill: true
max_advanced_fabbers: 50
max_basic_fabbers: 20
metal_demand_check: 0.71
metal_drain_check: 0.54
micro_type: 2
min_advanced_fabbers: 3
min_basic_fabbers: 2
name: "Absurd"
neural_data_mod: 1
per_expansion_delay: 0
percent_air: 0.2
percent_bot: 0.25
percent_naval: 0.05
percent_orbital: 0.05
percent_vehicle: 0.45
personality_tags: Array[2]
priority_scout_metal_spots: true
starting_location_evaluation_radius: 400
unable_to_expand_delay: 0
```

Currently my code is as follows:

```js
_.sample(_.keys(_.omit(absurdPersonalities, "aipRandom")))
```

This returns a random key as a string from the object, such as `"aipAir"`

But when I chain the code

```js
_.chain(absurdPersonalities).sample().keys().omit("aipRandom").value()
```

It returns:

```
Object {0: "display_name", 1: "percent_vehicle", 2: "percent_bot", 3: "percent_air", 4: "percent_naval", 5: "percent_orbital", 6: "personality_tags", 7: "metal_drain_check", 8: "energy_drain_check", 9: "metal_demand_check", 10: "energy_demand_check", 11: "micro_type", 12: "go_for_the_kill", 13: "priority_scout_metal_spots", 14: "enable_commander_danger_responses", 15: "neural_data_mod", 16: "unable_to_expand_delay", 17: "per_expansion_delay", 18: "factory_build_delay_min", 19: "adv_eco_mod", 20: "adv_eco_mod_alone", 21: "fabber_to_factory_ratio_basic", 22: "fabber_to_factory_ratio_advanced", 23: "fabber_alone_on_planet_mod", 24: "basic_to_advanced_factory_ratio", 25: "factory_alone_on_planet_mod", 26: "min_basic_fabbers", 27: "max_basic_fabbers", 28: "min_advanced_fabbers", 29: "max_advanced_fabbers", 30: "starting_location_evaluation_radius", 31: "name", 32: "percent_land"}
```

I'm unclear on where I've gone wrong in chaining this, or whether this is simply something that cannot be chained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first (working) expression first performs `omit`, then `keys` and finally `sample`. Note how that expression is resolved from the inside out.

When you chain, you must keep the same order:

```
_.chain(absurdPersonalities).omit("aipRandom").keys().sample().value()
```